# How to use Storage Access Framework (SAF) and URI editing text file in the shared storage correctly?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-11, storage-access-framework

(Edit) Answer by @blackapps: Change "w" to "wt". And it works!

//-------------------------------------------//

I follow the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) to write a simple text editor, but the result is weird.

The function I want to achieve: A text file that record what I want to eat today.

The first time I write "pineapple" to the text file. The content of text file is "pineapple". However, the second time I write "apple" to the text file. The content of text file is "applepple". It looks like just replace the first five character of previous content.

My problem is: How to make the content record "apple" rather than "applepple"? I want to use the SAF and URI. I don't want to use the direct path to access the file.

I create and edit the text file in the Download folder.
I run the app on Android 11, targetSdkVersion 30.
The following is the code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //--call this only once
//        createFile(MediaStore.Downloads.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    }

    private String todayFood = "pineapple";//change here to apple
    private static final int CREATE_FILE = 1;
    private static final int OPEN_FILE = 2;

    private void createFile(Uri pickerInitialUri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "foodFile");
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
    }

    public void onOpenFileBtn(View v){//button click event
        openFile(MediaStore.Downloads.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    }

    private void openFile(Uri pickerInitialUri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_FILE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
        if (requestCode == OPEN_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                outputToFile(uri);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            System.out.println("create successful");
        }
    }

    public void outputToFile(Uri fileUri) {
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            fileOutputStream.write(todayFood.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
            pfd.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

//-------------------------------------------//

//--What I have tried :

I have tried to use the direct path, and it work correctly. I think the reason is that it creates a new file to replace the original file. However, I just don't want to use direct path.

```java
public void outputToFile(Uri fileUri) {
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File f = new File(dir.getPath(), "foodFile.txt");

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        outputStream.write(todayFood.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried the PrintWriter to clear the content, but it also need the direct path to create File first then put in PrintWriter.

```java
public void outputToFile(Uri fileUri) {
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    try {
        File f = new File(dir.getPath(), "foodFile.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f);
        writer.print("");
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried to use OutputStream to create PrintWriter, but it doesn’t work.

```java
public void outputToFile(Uri fileUri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        writer.print("");
        writer.write("apple");
        writer.close();
        pfd.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also tried to create and edit the text file in the other folder, like Document folder, but it doesn’t work too.

I have tried to request runtime permission, but it has another problem I can't solve now.

Comment: Change "w" to "wt".

Comment: Thank you, it work! I read the document, but it doesn't explain too much. It just says " "rwt" modes implies a file on disk that supports seeking."

Comment: W==write, t==truncate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
public void outputToFile(String text) {
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
try {
   File logFile = new File(dir.getPath(), "abc.txt");
   BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
   buf.append(text);
   buf.newLine();
   buf.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that this could work, but I hope I could not use direct path.